# HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jasper.el.ELContextImpl

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, myeclipse

When I try to browse "localhost:8080" on myeclipse, I get the following error:

```
type Exception report

message java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jasper.el.ELContextImpl

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jasper.el.ELContextImpl
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:343)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)


root cause 

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jasper.el.ELContextImpl
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.prepareExpression(Validator.java:1568)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:747)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$ELExpression.accept(Node.java:954)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:475)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1795)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:217)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:373)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
```

Comment: I think this question is not a duplication. I encountered the issue, and solved by removing `jsp-api.jar` and `servlet-api.jar` from path `/Library/Java/Extensions` (on macOS) - these two files were copied to there by a suggestion from a book which use Ant to control the compilation.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to run a Web app on Jetty server? The error NoClassDefFoundError means you do not have the jar file required to run that code.

Here is the stackoverflow question on the same issue.

[org.apache.jasper.el.ELContextImpl cannot be cast to org.apache.jasper.runtime.ELContextImpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384779/org-apache-jasper-el-elcontextimpl-cannot-be-cast-to-org-apache-jasper-runtime-e)

If you are using the Eclipse IDE, I recommend you to download the Eclipse Jetty plugin

https://code.google.com/p/run-jetty-run/

or in your eclipse under help -> Market place -> enter 'jetty' or 'jetty plugin' then download run-jetty-run plugin

Comment: The tags say its Tomcat.

Comment: Thanks, I copied the el-api.jar into the directory ".\jre\lib\ext". When I deleted the .jar, no error reported.

Answer (score 0):

In eclipse when there is a HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in developing web application whether tomcat or jetty etc make sure to put the needed .jar files in the lib folder under the WEB-INF folder (/WEB-INF/lib) to solve the error

Answer (score 0):

I had the similar issue while trying to access `localhost:8080`.
This is happening because tomcat is able to detect more than 1 copy of jasper.jar
jsp-api,jasper-el.

The issue is due to conflicting jars.

Please remove the above jars from

1. `java/jdk(version)/jre/lib/ext`
2. Also remove the above jars from your web application lib directory.

Restart the tomcat and it will work fine.