# NoClassDefFoundError for tomcat 8.0.15/jasper/tiles 3.0.5

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, tiles

I'm getting the following exception and not sure if the problem is in tomcat 8.0.15 or if there is some incompatibility of other libraries:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: ServletException including path '/WEB-INF/views/layout/baseLayout.jsp'.
    at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletUtil.wrapServletException(ServletUtil.java:61) ~[tiles-request-servlet-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
    at org.apache.tiles.request.servlet.ServletRequest.doInclude(ServletRequest.java:245) ~[tiles-request-servlet-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
    at org.apache.tiles.request.AbstractClientRequest.dispatch(AbstractClientRequest.java:54) ~[tiles-request-api-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
    at org.apache.tiles.request.render.DispatchRenderer.render(DispatchRenderer.java:47) ~[tiles-request-api-1.0.6.jar:1.0.6]
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:259) ~[tiles-core-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:397) ~[tiles-core-3.0.5.jar:3.0.5]
    ... 37 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jasper.el.ELContextImpl
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.getJspAttribute(Validator.java:1414) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.checkXmlAttributes(Validator.java:1231) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.visit(Validator.java:879) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1536) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2428) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2434) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:464) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2376) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator.validateExDirectives(Validator.java:1846) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:217) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:564) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]
```

Any ideas?

- JDK 8u25
- Tomcat 8.0.15
- Spring 4.1.2
- Tiles 3.0.5

Comment: org.apache.jasper.el.ELContextImpl is not found at runtime. jar is the issue place fresh concerned jar in lib of server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. Another component was including spring boot jar which was as a dependency including tomcat 7.0.54 libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure jasper.jar is present in tomcat/lib.
If missing, add it, if not, try Tomcat>Clean... from Eclipse

Comment: jasper.jar is present otherwise I would have got NCDFE much earlier
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jasper.el.ELContextImpl
 at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.getJspAttribute(Validator.java:1414) ~[jasper.jar:8.0.15]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are missing el-api.jar as mentioned in [HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.jasper.el.ELContextImpl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624487/http-status-500-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-could-not-initialize-class-org)

kind regards,
soilworker

Comment: It's not missing, but it's related to that problem:
   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.add(CompositeELResolver.java:49)
 at org.apache.jasper.el.ELContextImpl.<clinit>(ELContextImpl.java:87)
 at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Validator$ValidateVisitor.prepareExpression(Validator.java:1615)

Answer (score 0):

Add servlet-api.jar, jsp-api.jar,el-api.jar to the JRE system libraries in eclipse

Windows - Preferences - Installed JREs -

select the existing jre and cleck edit to add the jars.

Comment: I have added all three jar files but no luck. Still getting an error related to the class `ELContextImpl`. With tomcat 7 my project is running without any problems.