# Spring boot war file deploy on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, deployment, spring-boot, war

I use Spring Boot 1.2.4.RELEASE with [gs-rest-service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) source file.
I got:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2015:09:59:25 +0300] "GET /gs-rest-service-0.1.0/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1021
```

There are no other exceptions in Tomcat logs.

I have read related questions, but my test doesn't run.
[Spring Boot War deployed to Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904594/spring-boot-war-deployed-to-tomcat)

I have read [howto-create-a-deployable-war](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file) and [Packaging executable jar and war files](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging).

Maybe I miss something.

My source:

1.pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>        
        <start-class>hello.Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>


    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

2.Application.java

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(Application.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

Files Greeting.java and GreetingController.java are not changed.

Comment: How do you host and test your WAR?

Comment: I copy war file to webapp directory and I can see my app in tomcat manager  page. Then I try to go "greeting page" at http://localhost:8080/gs-rest-service-0.1.0/greeting

Comment: java -jar gs-rest-service-0.1.0.war works fine.

Comment: bun i use link  localhost:8080/greeting

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just tried this here, and could reproduce the exact same behaviour.

As silly as it sounds, most likely you are running your external tomcat under a Java 1.7 JRE (speculation), while having compiled your code against 1.8 (we know this from your pom).

Strangely, there is no error, and the app appears in the manager app, but then you get a 404 when you're trying to access it.

One way to confirm this is to look at your tomcat log output. Do you see the Spring Boot banner? Probably not.

Comment: Hi, I set the java version to java 8 using  sudo update-java-alternatives  -s java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64. After that I restarted tomcat server. The problem is still not resolved. How can we keep using Java 8 here?

Comment: Hi, I had to change the JAVA_HOME property in /etc/default/tomcat7 to Java 8. After that it started working. Your comment above about wrong Java version helped a lot. Thanks.

Comment: @ci_ I have checked the version of java used my maven to build project and the version of java used by tomcat and both are java 1.8. I am seeing the spring boot banner in logs and not able to figure out what went wrong. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `localhost:8080/gs-rest-service/greeting` on your Tomcat. Tomcat usually gives each WAR application it hosts a name. This name is than used as root part of your URL. In most cases it is name of the WAR file, which is `gs-rest-service` in your case.

Comment: I pointed earlier. I copy war file to webapp directory and I can see my app in tomcat manager page. Then I try to go "greeting page" at localhost:8080/gs-rest-service-0.1.0/greeting. This link from tomcat manager page and add  greeting at the end.

Comment: Did you try localhost:8080/gs-rest-service/greeting?

Comment: Yes. I try to go at this link.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2015:11:12:58 +0300] "GET /gs-rest-service/greeting HTTP/1.1" 404 -

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [18/Jun/2015:11:14:29 +0300] "GET /gs-rest-service-0.1.0/greeting HTTP/1.1" 404 1045

Comment: can you post your tomcat directory structure? especially webapps folder.