# How to create deployable springboot war

Tags: maven, tomcat, deployment, spring-boot, war

I am trying to create a maven spring boot application to be deployed in Tomcat.  I am following what is suggested in Spring docs and other stackoverflow suggestions- war, Application.java extending SpringBootServletInitializer, removing spring-boot-maven-plugin from build plugins etc. War file is generated and is deployed in tomcat. But what I found is all static files are packaged under /WEB-INF/classes folder and I am not able to access the page. My project structure is as below:

[image: structure]

Can anybody tell me how I can package the war properly to be deployed in Tomcat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That doesn't change anything.

If you put your static assets in `src/main/resources/static` (and they end up in `WEB-INF/classes/static`), Spring Boot will serve them properly. So a `src/main/resources/static/foo.png` will be available at `http://localhost:8080/your-context/foo.png` if the context of your webapp is `your-context`.

Regarding the configuration, you can also go on start.spring.io, click advanced and chose war and you'll get an empty project pre-configured.

Or you can click this: https://start.spring.io/#!packaging=war

Comment: I have tried adding static resources in static but in wain. In fact /static (or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources is ok as per spring docs. [link](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html)

Comment: are you trying to access that home.html thing? That must be in `src/main/resources/static/index.html`.

Comment: Yes Stephane, I want to package the contents of src/main/resources/static folder in the context path when I build the war in Tomcat. I am looking for a way to package the contents of static folder to context path, like traditional web applications.

Comment: I am sorry to disappoint you but there's is nothing to do, really. Perhaps I don't understand what you're trying to do? I've created [a simple application](https://github.com/snicoll-scratches/test-war-static) that showcases what I mean. Check [the commit](https://github.com/snicoll-scratches/test-war-static/commit/56a9088cf40d0fef81fa04f2c36c3502958f4f70) for more details.

Comment: I have deployed the sample application without making any change to my tomcat 8 server, but I am not able to make it , I am not sure why.

Comment: I am sorry, I went as far as I could.

Comment: Fine no problem.. one last question ..Do I have to change any tomcat settings?

Comment: Nope. To test this I just downloaded tomcat, unzip, copy the war to webapps and run it. And it worked so I have no idea why it does not work for you.

Comment: I solved the issue .. it's because java compilation version. I build the project using java 1,8, but my tomcat was running on JRE -7. Finally it worked .. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because of version issue. I compiled the application with Java 8 and deployed it in tomcat running under JRE 7. It may help someone facing the same issue.
I got the clue from the below post:
[Spring boot war file deploy on Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30908579/spring-boot-war-file-deploy-on-tomcat).