# How to Deploy spring boot application using Eureka Server in windows

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, spring-boot-maven-plugin

If i was using apache tomcat as web server then i can simply take the Jar file and deploy in apache running in windows.

How can i deploy same when using Eureka Server in windows?

Do we have any server installation of Eureka?

Comment: You cannot deploy a jar file in tomcat. Also there is no such thing as Eureka Server...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot War deployed to Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904594/spring-boot-war-deployed-to-tomcat)

Answer (score 0):

Kiran, Each Spring Boot application you developed is **standalone** application. Whenever application is built embedded tomcat is packed inside the package. So it means it does not require extra effort for you side, just port the application to target machine and double click the application -> it will start its magic.

thus, created package is **not suitable** for separate running tomcat as it contains  unnessary stuff.

If you don't want to deploy on **separate tomcat** instead of standalone then follow guide

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html