# Can't access REST Controller with Spring Boot autoconfiguration

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I am trying to create a simple REST service with Spring Boot following [this tutorial](http://spring.io/guides/tutorials/bookmarks/). The "Hello World" html file from the webapp folder (`index.html`) is opening on `http://localhost:8080/my-rest-app/` (I created a Maven-Web-App because I want to have a "Welcome Page" for the Service). But if I try to access the REST service on `http://localhost:8080/my-rest-app/user` I get a 404 message.

pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>service</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-rest-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>my-rest-app</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Application.java:

```
package service.my.rest.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
//@ComponentScan({"service.my.rest.app", "service.my.rest.app.controller"})
//@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = UserController.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

UserController.java:

```
package service.my.rest.app.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getUser() {
        return "Hello";
    }

}
```

What am I missing? Is the URL to the service wrong? I read somewhere that the context path of the Spring Boot REST service is always `/`, that would meant that I have to access the service over `http://localhost:8080/my-rest-app/` but this does not working ether (without `index.html`). Changing the context path in the `application.properties` with `server.contextPath=/my-rest-app` and `server.port=8080` also didn't help.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're using war packaging instead of just a jar?

Comment: Remove the `@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)` from `getUser()` method. It'll invoke it via get method without the annotation + you're not specifiying a value in it.

Comment: @chrylis I need to run the REST service on a Tomcat along with a normal webpage. Therefore the html files and the service are in the same war package. Actually I did not choose. Netbeans did the packaging and the Deploying on the server.

Comment: Spring Boot will happily serve HTML and JSON, even from the exact same URL if desired. There's no need to use an external container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was the build and deploy process. Thank you @chrylis for the hint.

```
package service.my.rest.app;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"service.my.rest.app"})
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    private static Class<Application> application = Application.class;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(application, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(application);
    }

}
```

I had to extend my App to [build and deploy a war file](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html), because [Spring Boot is actually designed to produce a jar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27905419).

Comment: Mine issue was component scan not having the correct package as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your controller is into an external  module you can provvide whitch componet autoconfigure by filling file:
**src/main/resources/MATA_INF/sping.factories**

if i.e your controller is:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> execCommand(ComandoStr msg) {
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/exec")
@RestController
public class ExecController {

@PostMapping(value = "command")
public ResponseEntity<?> execCommand(ComandoStr msg) {
   ...
}
```

}

in sping.factories you need to add entry

```
imp.macchina.webapi.ExecController
```

then the controller get registered