# Deploying Spring WAR to Tomcat-based docker

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, docker

I have followed through Spring's [Building a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) tutorial and created a dummy webapp (with "Build with Maven" instructions). I build and package the WAR. Then I run it with this command:

```
java -jar ./target/Dummy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
```

I can see the dummy JSON endpoint at http://localhost:8080/greeting/.

Now I want to containerize the app with Docker so I can further test it without the needs to install Tomcat to system space. This is the `Dockerfile` I created:

```
FROM tomcat:7-jre8-alpine

# copy the WAR bundle to tomcat
COPY /target/Dummy-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war

# command to run
CMD ["catalina.sh", "run"]
```

I build and run the docker binding to http://localhost:8080. I can see the Tomcat welcome page on "http://localhost:8080". But I couldn't see my app on neither:

- http://localhost:8080/app/
- http://localhost:8080/app/greeting/
- http://localhost:8080/greeting/

How should I track down the issue? What could be the problem?

### Update 1: The Tomcat admin interface screenshot

[image: Tomcat Admin]

Comment: Have you checked the log files of Tomcat?

Comment: What does http://localhost:8080/manager/html say? Is the app sucessfully deployed?

Comment: @LucianovanderVeekens It seems to be deployed successfully. See the screenshot I added above.

Comment: @khmarbaise: Catalina logs show that the WAR deployed successfully.

Comment: How do you run the docker? `docker run -p 8080:8080 ...`?

Comment: @StanislavL: Yup. The port mapping is correct. I can see the Tomcat default landing page and manager with no problem. But when I try to visit the WAR path (see the paths I tried in the original post), they all give me a Tomcat standard 404 page.

Comment: Could be it's not real war file? Because you run it to test as a springboot jar (the only diff is the file name). Try to setup tomcat locally and manually copy the war to webapps. Guess structure of the war could be wrong - e.g. missing web.xml or something like this.

Comment: @StanislavL: Thanks for the advice. I will try it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Application.java` file in [the example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) looks like this:

```
package hello;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

This is a valid SpringBoot application, but NOT a deployable application to Tomcat. To make it deployable, you can can:

1. redefine`Application` to extend `SpringBootServletInitializer` from Spring framework web support; then
2. override the `configure` method:

   ```
   package hello;

   import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
   import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;    

   @SpringBootApplication
   public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

       @Override
       protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
           return application.sources(Application.class);
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
       }

   }
   ```

No need to change the `pom.xml` file (or any other configurations).

After rebuilding the dockerfile and run it with proper port binding, the greeting example endpoint will be available through: http://localhost:8080/app/greeting/

### References

1. [Spring Boot War deployed to Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904594/spring-boot-war-deployed-to-tomcat)
2. [Spring Boot Reference Guide: Create a deployable war file](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file)