# Update Spring Boot to generate WAR file instead of JAR file

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I made a web service with spring boot and gradle. My project is using gradle.
I have to make dynamic web project and integrate UI and web service.
 How can I update my web service so that it will generate WAR file instead of JAR file??

Comment: packaging "war" instead of "jar" does not help?

Comment: @spi I have to integrate it with a dynamic web project(UI) so I need a WAR file instead of jar.

Comment: yes I've understand... Then you declare your packaging (in your gradle file) as "war" instead of the (default) value "jar": https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot War deployed to Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904594/spring-boot-war-deployed-to-tomcat)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please check these guides here:

[Spring-boot Gradle Plugin War Packaging](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-gradle-packaging) OR 
[Create Deployable War on Application Server](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-create-a-deployable-war-file)
More specifically: you will need to change the type of packaging in the build.gradle file to "war".

Quoting from the second link:

> **Note** :- If you’re using Gradle, you need to modify `build.gradle` to apply the
>    war plugin to the project:

```
 apply plugin: 'war'  // add this plugin to build.gradle.
```

Comment: Downvoter: could you please explain, so that I can improve the answer?

Comment: I don't know why the downvote. It worked for me. I was struggling to find this. An upvote for you

Comment: For Maven add `<packaging>war</packaging>` inside your `<project ...>`.