# Get 404 found error after deploy spring application war file in Tomcat

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat

I am trying to deploy spring application war file in tomcat. When we place war file in tomcat webapps folder, the folder with same name was created. But  when we access by using host:8080/warname is displaying 404 found error.

I have updated the Packaging as War and Tomcat dependency in pom.xml file as well. But still facing 404 found error. Anyone help me with this if any configuration changes missing in my end.

Also please help me with tell war folder structure in the tomcat to identify war file deployed properly in our end.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot War deployed to Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904594/spring-boot-war-deployed-to-tomcat)

Comment: Thanks for your response. It is working with my sample spring MVC application. But it is not working with my live application. I need to call application controller as http://host:8080/warname/oauth/token.But when i access this url after deploy application, it shows 404 not found error. Can we get details about what we need to set on groupid, startclass and parent attribute in pom.xml fil, also how to call controller and method in tomcat.