# deploy a eureka war server into tomcat8.5 ,but it can not access

Tags: tomcat, deployment, server, netflix-eureka

I create a eureka project in IDEA and it works well. But when I pack it into war and throw into webapp directory of tomcat 8.5. After restart tomcat,I can not access it by the url localhost:8761

EurekaApplication.java

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaApplication {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaApplication.class,args);
    }
}
```

application.yml

```
server:
  port: 8761

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serverUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:${server.port}/eureka/

spring.cloud.config.discovery.enabled: true
```

Comment: In IDEA, it can start well and I can access it by localhost:8761

Comment: after i put  war into tomcat ,and restart tomcat ,I do not find any error log from log file.

Comment: Did you try this one - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27904594/spring-boot-war-deployed-to-tomcat

Answer (score 2):

Your EurekaApplication class should extends SpringBootServletInitializer and override configure method like bellow:

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {

    return builder.sources(EurekaApplication.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check tomcat port number in server.xml
and use that port number to load eureka server.

The eureka server access according to instance available in `/webapp`
of your tomcat

For-example, I have folder `discovery-service` , the tomcat port is `8761`:
`http://localhost:8761/discovery-service/`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30546749)