# Tomcat does not unpack spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat, deployment

thank you for your attention in reading my problem;

I'm trying to deploy a spring boot application but when I put it in the tomcat webapps folder it doesn't load my application, does anyone know what could be happening?

I already tried to run several versions of java changing the system variables, I used several versions of tomcat but none unzip the application

I'm using java version 17
and version apache-tomcat-9.0.71

[Log Tomcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53sUS.png)

[Tomcat Past](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3WeUR.png)

Answer (score 1):

I thought Spring Boot came with a pre-installed web server, so there is no need to use this method. Why don't you use the current method which supports auto deployment of your application?

Comment: I would like to put it in production on a server computer starting in tomcat, without having to install eclipse

Answer (score 1):

An Spring Boot application is a ready to run jar file which contains tomcat/jetty and can be run with `java -jar <your app>.jar`.
When you want to run an application in tomcat you should build a `.war` file.

======================================

As found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27905557/2144466

Did you follow this guide: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.traditional-deployment

and do you have a class which extends `SpringBootServletInitializer` andd overwrites the `configure` method:
`
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

```
@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(MyApplication.class);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
}
```

`

Comment: the war file was created correctly, however when I add it to the webapps folder in tomcat it does not start with the server in the log

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below.

- Rename your war file at location webapps from web-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war to web.war
- restart tomcat.
- open url (http://localhost:8080/web) in browser.

Comment: Or you can go with jar build of spring boot and run `java -jar web.jar --server.port=9000`  in commad prompt or terminal and open (http://localhost:9000/web)

Comment: I did that and it returned " HTTP Status 404 - Not Found "

Comment: the project is not uploading in the log, will it be some incompatibility between versions of java, tomcat and maven?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem.

Apparently it was version incompatibility between spring, tomcat and java, by adjusting the system variables I can deploy both java 11 and java 17 applications.

Even though I managed to find a solution, I thank the friends above for dedicating their time to trying to solve my problem.