# How to deploy a spring boot MVC application in traditional tomcat webapps folder?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I created a simple spring mvc application following a springboot springmvc with gradle example.[image]

Below is the structure. 
src/main/java - This is where all the code base is there.
src/main/resources - This is where all the resources/templates are there.

```
    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application {

        public static void main(String[] args) {         
            SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        }

    }
```

And just writing the above class and with zero configurations, I was able to launch my spring-mvc web application (which is very cool). (through commands gradlew build and gradlew bootrun)
But coming from a traditional web application development and deployment background, I am wondering how to create a war file out of this and deploy that into a tomcat webapps folder.

Also, where to keep all the new resources (like js files, css, etc.). We would generally have a WEB-INF folder where we keep them, but what to do here.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741816/deploy-spring-boot-to-tomcat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

meskobalazs answered your question about the resources when building a **war** deployment (but notice that `src/main/webapp` is not read as a resource folder in a **jar** deployment, you have to add it as a resource in this case).

When you want to change your Spring-Boot app to a web deployment you basically have to do two things:

- convert the packaging of your project from jar to war
- change the dependency of the embedded tomcat to provided

Further details can be found on the [Spring-Boot documentation site](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-traditional-deployment)

Comment: There is one more important step. You should also verify that the war file's base name matches the spring server.context-name in src/main/resource/application.properties. This way, the URLs will be the same when accessing the Sprng Boot loaded app vs the web app in Tomcat. For example, to see http://localhost:post/mycontext from both deployments, put the line "server.context-path=/mycontext" in src/main/resource/application.properties and then deploy mycontext-1.0.0.war to <tomcat>/webapps/mycontext.war

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot include Tomcat container.

You have to remove external Tomcat to deploy your project

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Maven** project you need to modify ***pom.xml*** to change the **packaging to war**, as follows

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
```

And If you are using **Gradle** project you need to modify ***build.gradle*** as follows

```
apply plugin: 'war'
```

Once you build project it will create war file, so you can easily deploy in any tomcat server webapps folder