# Spring-Boot Maven, missing dependency @RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, intellij-idea

I'm new to the Springboot and Maven area and wanted to ask what I did wrong here / why it doesn't work that way.

[My Code](https://ibb.co/B39nbSF)

[Says, missing Maven dependency](https://ibb.co/Lrnv0pX)

Normally it should add after I type the annotation "@RestController" -> import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

What should I do?

My POM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>de.martinm</groupId>
    <artifactId>SimpleTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SimpleTest</name>
    <description>Test project using Spring</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: Show us your pom.xml

Comment: Can you paste the pom.xml here?

Comment: Make sure you have added `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency to your pom.xml

Comment: Posted it right now

Comment: @Martixx add this depdendency <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deploy Spring Boot to Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741816/deploy-spring-boot-to-tomcat)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`@RestController` annotation is included in `spring-web-X.X.X.jar`
You need to include `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency in your `pom.xml` file:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

by yl