# Spring mvc projects are conflicting while trying to run on single server

Tags: spring

I have two spring mvc projects. Single project executes without any problem but If I add another project to server and try to execute that one, it gives an error. 
I am not getting what exactly is conflicting. I am using bootstrap in both projects. Also many of  js, css and jar files are same.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show us the error msg (+stacktrace if any).

Comment: it gives msg as "an exception occured processing JSP page" for c:if tag

Comment: And that's all? I doubt it

Comment: Yes, that's all. That is why I am not getting what is going wrong.

Comment: Start is this :  stackTrace: classCastException org.apache..jasper.el.ELContextImpl cannot be cast to org.apache..jasper.el.ELContextImpl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was jasper.jar which was conflicting. I removed that and both the projects are executing fine. Refered this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12384779/org-apache-jasper-el-elcontextimpl-cannot-be-cast-to-org-apache-jasper-runtime-e)